# Plot Time Series Data in Line Graph in Power BI

Tags: time-series, powerbi, timeserieschart

How can I filter my time series data when the time series data is in columns? I'd like to create a drop down slicer because there are more than 20 things they are looking at and they want to pick and choose.

Thank you for the help.

[image]
[image: time series plot]

Answer (score 0):

You must convert it to Lines like that, create first the metrics and the dataset named as Plot Time Series Data in Line Graph in Power BI:

Thing 02_Day01 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 02]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 1))

Thing 03_Day01 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 03]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 1))

Thing 04_Day01 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 04]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 1))

Thing 02_Day02 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 02]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 2))

Thing 03_Day02 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 03]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 2))

Thing 04_Day02 = CALCULATE(sum(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 04]),FILTER(YOUR_DATASET,YOUR_DATASET[Day] = 2))

Plot Time Series Data in Line Graph in Power BI =
UNION (ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 02", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 02_Day01])),
       ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 03", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 03_Day01])),
       ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 04", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 04_Day01])),
       ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 02", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 02_Day02])),
       ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 03", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 03_Day02])),
       ROW ( "Category",    "Thing 04", "Day",      VALUE(YOUR_DATASET[Thing 04_Day02]))
      )

You should continue this code up the number of the days you want to represent in your chart.

Once you have done it, you can use your new dataset (table named Plot Time Series Data in Line Graph in Power BI ).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by doing the following:

In query editor leave the time series column alone and select all other thing columns
[image]

Then 'unpivot' the columns in the query editor and it will look like this:
[image]

Then, I could slice on the Thing column. I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GINbx-gOwNE) for help to unpivot.